# Dynamically parse Skype Web Control tags

Tags: html, reactjs, skype, skypedeveloper

I want to use [Skype Web Control](https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol) in my React application.
The problem is that when I add generated `span` tags in React component, they are not parsed by Skype SDK and no plugin is rendered.
How can I programmatically force Skype SDK to parse my DOM once again to find that new tags were added and render Skype plugin?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution found**

```
SkypeWebControl.SDK.start();
```

Comment: I assume this goes into the `componentDidMount` method? I'm wondering if it works with repeated calls.

Comment: Works fine in `componentDidUpdate` with repeated calls.